# Unwanted Menu Shown in PSX Fullscreen Mode

Tags: emulation, ps1

I see the File Quicksave and Debug menu even when in Full-screen mode in the PSX emulator (psxfin.exe v1.13). Since the forum is closed I thought I'd post the issue here. Platform is Win10 64-bit. Interestingly it's not occurring on another Win10 machine of mine and the setup was copied identically.

How to get rid of the menu?

Answer (score 4):

Right click the psxfin executable, go to properties, go to compatibility, tick disable fullscreen optimizations. You're welcome, it was bothering me too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the reason was I had compatibility to WinXP SP3 enabled.
All I had to to was turning compatibility off and that annoying menu bar stopped showing in full screen.

Win 10 64Bit